# Can't change discord channel name

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I will need to change name of certain voice channels.
I tried several examples but none of them worked for me.

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('Server ID');
let channel = guild.channels.get('Channel ID');
channel.setName('MY NAME WAS CHANGED!')
```

Error:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: guild.channels.get is not a function

Another example which is not working

```js
client.guilds.cache.get('Server ID').channels.get('Channel ID').channels.setName("MY NAME WAS CHANGED!");
```

Error:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: client.guilds.cache.get(...).channels.get is not a function

How I can change the channel name correctly?

Updated: I can get current name of my channel, but how can I change the name of it?

```js
  client.channels.fetch("MYID")
  .then(channel => console.log(`The channel name is: ${channel.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

> The channel name is: change-my-name

```js
  let channel = client.channels.fetch("ID")
  channel.setName("MY NAME WAS CHANGED!")
  .then(newChannel => console.log(`Channel's new name is ${newChannel.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: channel.setName is not a function

Even after fetching channel, name cannot be changed by code i found at docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using guild.channels.fetch() instead of guild.channels.get().
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch
Note - As it returns a promise, make sure to either `await` it or use `.then()`.

Comment: It seems to be setName problem, whatever i do i can't change the name of the channel...

Comment: What's the output of your code when you change to .fetch()? Also, which discord.js version are you using?

Comment: `Unhandled rejection TypeError: channel.setName is not a function` When i used fetch instead of get from first example. Always the function problem... i can't figure out what is wrong...

Comment: discord.js should be the latest version.. i started like one week ago with discord APIS

Comment: Did you await the fetch?

Comment: No, how that would help or how to use it? I don't get it sorry.

Comment: `client.channels.fetch("ID")
  .then(channel => console.log(`The channel name is: ${channel.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);`
I got a response and i received my current channel name

Comment: But still don't know how to change the name of the channel

Comment: Since fetch() returns a promise, you needed to either use .then() or await it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  client.channels.fetch("ID")
  .then(channel => channel.setName("NewChannelName"));
  client.channels.fetch("ID2")
  .then(channel => channel.setName("NewChannelName2"));
```

Here is the solution. `guild.channels.get` seems to be outdated, that's why it didn't worked out for me probably.

With `client.channels.fetch("ID")` You're able to pick the ID and right after you can change your channel name. `.then(channel => channel.setName("YourNewChannelName"));`

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method must be used on the `cache` property.

```js
let channel = guild.channels.cache.get('Channel ID')
```

This however only gets it from the cache, which means not all the channels might be there. Using `fetch` fetches the channel from the API meaning it doesn’t have to be in cache. Beware this method returns a `Promise` which you will have to `await` (Be sure it’s an async callback!)

```js
let channel = await guild.channels.fetch('Channel ID')
```

Then to set the name, write this under the declaration

```js
channel.setName("name-of-channel")
```